# VB.NET - Access shared member through Type

Tags: vb.net

I'm wondering if this is possible.  In my Test function below I want to

1. Check if `T` is of type `BaseClass`; throw an error if it's not.
2. Get the value of `SomeText` property of `BaseClass`.

   ```
   Class BaseClass

       Public Shared Property SomeText As String

   End Class

   Class Class1
       Inherits BaseClass

       Public Sub New()
           SomeText = "Class 1 here"
       End Sub

   End Class
   ```

...

```
    Sub Main

        Test(GetType(Class1))
        Test(GetType(Class2))

    End Sub

    Sub Test(T As Type)

        ' Task 1: Check if T is of type BaseClass

        ' Task 2: Get the value of SomeText property of BaseClass

    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want to be setting the value of a shared member from inside an instance constructor?  While this /may/ be correct, it's not something one usually sees, so I just wanted to be sure.  A `Shared Sub New` is generally the way one initializes shared members.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep your test signature and do the following:

```
    If T.BaseType Is GetType(BaseClass) Then
        Dim CurrentValue as String = BaseClass.SomeText
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("T must inherit from BaseClass")
    End If
```

Since this never actually creates an instance of your type, you may not get the string you are expecting.  If you haven't created an instance elsewhere you will only have an empty string.

You can generate an instance of your class from the type you sent if that is your goal:

```
    If T.BaseType Is GetType(BaseClass) Then
        Dim currentValue As String = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(T), BaseClass).SomeText
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("T must inherit from BaseClass")
    End If
```

Edit based on Comment about further subclassing:

If you want it to include the base type or any descendants you could use this if instead:

```
    If T Is GetType(EventBase) OrElse T.IsSubclassOf(GetType(EventBase)) Then

    End If
```

Comment: Using Type.BaseType will break if a BaseClass is subclassed (say BaseClassSub) and Class1 is changed to inherit from this new subclass. In this case, Class1 is still a subclass of BaseClass, just 1 level removed from direct inheritance.

Comment: I thought that was his goal.  Edited.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite test as follows (updated to reflect change to question):

```
Sub Test(T As Type)

    ' Task 1: Check if T is of type BaseClass
    If T.IsSubclassOf(GetType(BaseClass)) Then
       ' Task 2: Get the value of SomeText property of BaseClass
        Dim sValue As String
        ' Create an unused instance of BaseClass to ensure the current value of SomeText is assigned
        Dim oClass As BaseClass = DirectCast(System.Activator.CreateInstance(T), BaseClass)

        ' Get the value from BaseClass since it is a shared instance
        sValue = BaseClass.SomeText
    Else
       Throw New ArgumentException("T did not inherit from BaseClass")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: You mean `T As Type`, and you should use `CType(Activator.CreateInstance(T), BaseClass)` instead of `As New Class1`, like D..

Comment: @MarkHurd: Actually, this is exactly what the OP was asking for when I originally responded to the question. They specifically asked for the value of Class1, not of the class that inherited from BaseClass. Since they have changed their request, I will update my answer.

Comment: I think you may want to change you T parameter type to type from object considering the edits you made.